# How to adjust/manipulate labels in subfloat

Tags: tables, subfloats

Given the following code using `subfloat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=sf, labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=sf}

\usepackage{graphicx,txfonts}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:w1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{w1.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:s1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{s1.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:o1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{o1.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:d1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{d1.png}}\\

    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:w2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{w2.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:s2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{s2.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:o2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{o2.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:d2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{d2.png}}\\

\caption{Example of Challenging Conditions:
\protect\subref{subfig:w1} Weather1, 
\protect\subref{subfig:s1} Season1, 
\protect\subref{subfig:o1} Occlusion1, 
\protect\subref{subfig:d1} DayNigh1, 
and
\protect\subref{subfig:w2} Weather2, 
\protect\subref{subfig:s2} Season2, 
\protect\subref{subfig:o2} Occlusion2, 
\protect\subref{subfig:d2} DayNigh2, 
}
\label{fig:challenges}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

I get the following figure:
[image: got]

However, I would like to manipulate the labels such that I get rid of labels on the top (since they belong to same category) and get something similar to this figure instead:
[image: desired]

Recommended by @Simon adding the following code and using table:

```
\begin{table}[hb!]
    \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\sffamily
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}& 
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}\\    
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}& 
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}\\
                a) Weather & b) Season & c) Occlusion  & d) Day/Night
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Example of Challenging Conditions}\label{tab:challenges}   
    \end{table}
```

The results looks like:
[image: recom]

In which it misses `Figure 1:` in the caption.

Is there probably any hack around using `subfloat` to address this?

Cheers,

Comment: The code that you included in the question is ok, but it is not a minimum working example. Please, see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** to match the updated question

Instead of using a `figure` and `subfloats` you might use a `tabular`

[image: d]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=sf}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:w1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:s1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:o1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:d1}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
        
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:w2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:s2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:o2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:d2}\includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
                    
        \caption{Example of Challenging Conditions:
            (\subref{subfig:w1}) Weather1, 
            (\subref{subfig:s1}) Season1, 
            (\subref{subfig:o1}) Occlusion1, 
            (\subref{subfig:d1}) DayNigh1, 
            and
            (\subref{subfig:w2}) Weather2, 
            (\subref{subfig:s2}) Season2, 
            (\subref{subfig:o2}) Occlusion2, 
            (\subref{subfig:d2}) DayNigh2, 
        }
        \label{fig:challenges}
    \end{figure}

    

    \begin{figure}[hb!]
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\sffamily
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}& 
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}\\    
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}& 
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}&
            \includegraphics[width=0.245\textwidth]{example-image}\\
                a) Weather & b) Season & c) Occlusion  & d) Day/Night
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Example of Challenging Conditions}\label{fig:challenges2}  
    \end{figure}    

See the first column of figure \ref{fig:challenges2}.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! tnx dude :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for except It does not follow the figure numeric, e.g., Figure1: Example of Challenging Conditions.

Comment: @Färid Alijani  Perhaps you should update your question or make a new one. Now the answer replicates your last figure using `labelformat=empty`

Comment: @Färid Alijani Meanwhile replace `\begin{table}`  by `\begin{figure}` to see how it works.

Comment: updated my question and now with `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` it works like a charm :) could you also edit your response for future usages perhaps?